# Python multiprocessing: Incorrect synchorization caused subprocess locked up on waiter.acquire()

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

I was writing a concurrent workflow for a small test project, which involved the following workflow:

1. There are four distinct procedure, each accepting one param and returning one variable as the data required by the next procedure. Connecting each was 5 `multiprocess.Queue` object (a excessive one at the end for the constistency of function behavior).
2. Each function is wrapped by a simple daemon, that (what I intends to do) loops to process the data on the queue, pushing it to the next procedure while listening to a global flag notifying that whether the emptiness of the input queue is due to the end of processing, or a congestion further up the pipeline. The code is like this:

```py
def ProcessWrapper(procedure, input_queue, output_queue, total_tasks, done_queue):
    GlobalFlag = (done_queue.qsize() == total_tasks)
    while not GlobalFlag:
        GlobalFlag = (done_queue.qsize() == total_tasks)
        try:
            unit = input_queue.get()
            callback = procedure(unit)
        except queue.Empty:
            if not GlobalFlag:
                continue
            else:
                break
        while True:
            try:
                output_queue.put(callback)
            except queue.Full:
                time.sleep(60)
                continue
            break
        input_queue.task_done()
```

3. This daemon would be summoned by a `multiprocess.Pool` into subprocesses to perform different job. Since the input/output queue is iterative, I used a generator to make a `pool.starmap()` call. The code is as follow:

```py
# Getting the list of function object
procedure_dir = dir(Procedure.Singleton)
procedure_functions = [
    attribute
    for attribute in procedure_dir
    if inspect.isfunction(getattr(Procedure.Singleton, attribute))
]

# Bootstrapping code
def Test():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    # Generate file queue and analyze queue
    io_queue = {
        label: manager.Queue() for label in ["file_queue", "post_queue", "analyze_queue", "clean_queue", "done_queue"]
    }
    
    # Code Omitted for putting the initial task into file_queue.

    pbar.total = len(file_list)

    with mp.get_context("spawn").Pool(len(procedure_functions)) as pool:
        pool.starmap(
            Procedure.ProcessWrapper,
            [
                (procedure, io_queue[list(io_queue.keys())[i]], io_queue[list(io_queue.keys())[i + 1]], len(file_list), io_queue[list(io_queue.keys())[-1]]) #
                for i, procedure in enumerate(procedure_functions[:-1])
            ],
        )
```

But upon running, the code freezes in the first spawned subprocess (It did successfully spawned **5** subprocesses, which is absurd to me). When I got the trace from gdb, it seems like the code stucked at the `waiter.acquire()` call in the module code. I've definitely done wrong on the flag, should've used an actual lock, but I doubt this is the reason, for the code didn't even spawn into the first function of the first cycle (which would at least write a file).

I know I've certainly done something wrong, but is uncertain where, for I have no prior experience other than the document Python provides. Would be grateful if someone could instruct me on how to debug this kinds of problem, or points out where I've have fundamental misunderstanding about how concurrency works.

I've reviewed the answers on other revelant questions, including the use of `spawn` context rather than `fork`, and the possible leaking on `with` sentences. But none of the solution they provide solved this.